# Date is not showing up properly in Liferay portlet

Tags: liferay, liferay-aui

In my portlet I have one form where I am showing dates through following code

JSP:

```
<aui:input type="text" name="createdDate" size="10" value="" id="createdDate" label="" />
      <div class="calendar-icon" id="imageDiv">
 <span class="aui-icon aui-icon-calendar"></span>
 </div>
```

Script in JSP

```
renderCalendar('#imageDiv','#<portlet:namespace/>createdDate','#calendarDiv');
function renderCalendar(imageDiv,inputDisplay,calendarDiv)  {
  AUI().ready('aui-calendar', function(A) {
    var inputField1 = A.one(imageDiv); 
    var inputField2 = A.one(inputDisplay);

    var calendar1 = new A.Calendar({    
        dates: [ new Date() ],   
        dateFormat: '%d/%m/%Y',     
        selectMultipleDates: false,        
        after: {                        
            datesChange: function(event) {         
                        var formatted = event.target.getFormattedSelectedDates();       
                        inputField2.val(formatted); 
                        calendar1.toggle(); // hide after a date was selected        
                    }        
                }
    }).render(calendarDiv);   

    var boundingBoxCal1 = calendar1.get('boundingBox');  
    boundingBoxCal1.setX(inputField1.getX());         
    boundingBoxCal1.setY(inputField1.getY() + 25);      
    calendar1.hide(); 
    inputField1.on('click', function() { calendar1.toggle(); });        
});
}
```

It is showing date on page but the problem is with layout Date text field and calender icon both not coming in same line.Please help me out 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

use `<span>` instead of `<div>`. `<div>` opens a new block while `<span>` will remain in the same line

Comment: Tried this but result is same.c

Answer (score 0):

Strange that `<span>` didn't fix your problem. Try floating your `<div>` to the left, as in,

```
<div class="calendar-icon" id="imageDiv" style="float: left;">
```